# Help getting test coverage for wrap class

Tags: apex, unit-test, wrapper-class

I have been writing a test class from a wrap class but I am stuck in 77%, I don't know what else to try. I will appreciate any help.

I added in the code the lines that are uncovered basically the second section (create task) of the "CreatedPlan()" is uncovered.

Controller:

```
 public class ServiceSelectClassController{

 //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects wrapService
 public List<wrapService> wrapServiceList {get; set;}
 public List<Service__c> selectedServices{get;set;}

 //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects wrapTask 
 public List<wrapTask> wrapTaskList {get; set;}
 public List<Service_Task_Library__c> selectedTasks{get;set;}


 //to upload
 public List<Service_Committment__c > ServicetoUpload;
 public List<task> TasksToUpload;


 //to get the brandManager or categoryManager or specialist with dynamic query
 public SObject s;
 public String  AssignedTo      { get; set; }


 public ServiceSelectClassController(){

    if(wrapServiceList == null) {
        wrapServiceList = new List<wrapService>();
        for(Service__c s: [select Id, Name,Category__c,Prerequisite__c,Service__c from Service__c Order by Id ASC]) {
            // As each Service is processed we create a new wrapService object and add it to the wrapServiceList
            wrapServiceList.add(new wrapService(s));
        }
    }
 }

 public void ServiceProcessSelected() {

 //This list will hold the selected services values 
 selectedServices = new List<Service__c>();

 //first get selected accounts comparing with the  wrpaServiceList
    for(wrapService wrapServiceObj : wrapServiceList) {
        if(wrapServiceObj.selected == true) {
            selectedServices.add(wrapServiceObj.serv);
        }
    }

//Knowing the selected services, get the taks relate to 
//insert to wrap class

    wrapTaskList = new List<wrapTask>();
    for(Service_Task_Library__c ta: [select Id, Name, Service__c, Subject__c, Assigned_To__c from Service_Task_Library__c  where Service__c IN : selectedServices Order by Service__c ASC]) {
       // As each Task is processed we create a new wrapTask object and add it to the wrapTaskList
        wrapTaskList.add(new wrapTask(ta));

    }

 }

  public void TaskProcessSelected() {

  //This list will hold the selected task values 
  selectedTasks = new List<Service_Task_Library__c>();

  //first get task selcted comparing with the  wrapTaskList
  for(wrapTask wrapTaskObj : wrapTaskList) {
        if(wrapTaskObj.ChildSelected == true) {
            selectedTasks.add(wrapTaskObj.tas);

        }
    }

}

 public void CreatePlan() {
 //create services and their tasks here  

    //get brand__c id
    String BrandId   = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
    //get Account linked to brand
    String AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Acc'); 


    //initialize list ToUpload
    ServicetoUpload = new List<Service_Committment__c >();
    TasksToUpload   = new List<task>();


    //here for loop to get values
    for (Service__c row : selectedServices) 
    {

        //create new Service_Committment__c 
        Service_Committment__c service = new Service_Committment__c(
                    Brand_Plan__c = BrandId,
                    Service_ID__c = String.valueof(row.get('Id'))

                    );

                    ServicetoUpload.add(service);

    }

   //insert outside loop
   insert ServicetoUpload;  //this line is uncovered 


   //once the services where inserted, get them back to insert their tasks
   //get sevice committment(s) for this Brand plan
   for(Service_Committment__c so : ServicetoUpload) //this line is uncovered 
   {      

       //here for loop to get values from selected tasks
        for (Service_Task_Library__c row2 : [select Id, Name, Service__c, Subject__c,Assigned_To__c from Service_Task_Library__c  where Service__c =: so.Service_ID__c AND Id IN: selectedTasks  ]) //this line is uncovered 
               {

     //get Assign to from Task_library and match the labels from account
     //create dynamic query getting the assign to field and match it in accounts
                    String query  = 'SELECT '+ row2.Assigned_To__c + + ' FROM Account' + ' WHERE id= \'' +  AccountId + '\''; //this line is uncovered 
                    s = database.query(query);  //this line is uncovered 
     //finally save the CategoryManager or BrandManager or specialists
                    AssignedTo =  '' + s.get(row2.Assigned_To__c);   //this line is uncovered   

                 // //this create task is uncovered  
                     //create new tasks
                     task newtask= new task(

                     OwnerId  = AssignedTo ,
                     Subject  = String.valueof(row2.get('Subject__c')),
                     WhatId   = so.Id

                     );

                     TasksToUpload.add(newtask);//this line is uncovered 

              }

   }

 //insert outside loop
 insert TasksToUpload; //this line is uncovered 

 }

  // This is our wrapper/container class for services.This wrapper class contains both the object Service__c and a Boolean value
 public class wrapService {
    public Service__c serv {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    public wrapService(Service__c s) {
        serv = s;
        selected = false;
    }
 }

 // This is our wrapper/container class for services.This wrapper class contains both the object Service_Task_Library__c  and a Boolean value
public class wrapTask {
    public Service_Task_Library__c tas {get; set;}
    public Boolean ChildSelected {get; set;}

    public wrapTask(Service_Task_Library__c t) {
        tas = t;
        ChildSelected = false;
    }
 }
}
```

Test class

```
@istest
private class test_ServiceSelectClassController {

static testmethod void testServiceSelectClassController () {


//create the records to run the controller

 Profile pServ = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];

 User UserServ = new User(alias = 'standt', email='UserServiceSelected@testorg.com',emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                                         localesidkey='en_US', profileid = pServ.Id, timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='UserServiceSelected@net.com');

               insert UserServ;


 Account account = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1', Category_Manager__c =   UserServ.id , Brand_Manager__c= UserServ.id, Specialist__c=UserServ.id);
    insert account; 

 Brand_Plan__c brand = new Brand_Plan__c (Account__c = account.id);
    insert brand;

 Service__c service = new Service__c (Service__c='Staff Education');
    insert service;

 Service_Task_Library__c serviceTaskLibrary = new Service_Task_Library__c( Service__c = service.id, Subject__c='Create Marketplace Policy', Assigned_To__c='Brand_Manager__c');
    insert    serviceTaskLibrary ;   

 Service_Committment__c serviceCommittment = new Service_Committment__c(   Brand_Plan__c = Brand.Id, Service_ID__c = service.id);
    insert  serviceCommittment ; 

Task task =  new Task( OwnerId= UserServ.id, Subject= serviceTaskLibrary.subject__c  ,  WhatId = serviceCommittment .Id);
    insert task;


 //initialize page putting values ID and Acc
  PageReference tpageRef = Page.ServiceSelected;
  Test.setCurrentPage(tpageRef);

  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', brand.id );
  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Acc',account.id);

  System.assertEquals( brand.id, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
 System.assertEquals( account.id, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Acc'));


  //initialize controller
  ServiceSelectClassController serv = new ServiceSelectClassController();


 //following the order of execution from controller

  serv.ServiceProcessSelected() ;

  ServiceSelectClassController.wrapService  wrapService = new ServiceSelectClassController.wrapService (service);
    wrapService.serv = service;
    wrapService.selected= false;


  serv.TaskProcessSelected() ;

  ServiceSelectClassController.wrapTask  wrapTask = new ServiceSelectClassController.wrapTask (serviceTaskLibrary );
    wrapTask.tas = serviceTaskLibrary ;
    wrapTask.ChildSelected= false;        



 serv.CreatePlan();

  }
 }
```

Comment: You need to post the lines not covered (better yet, indicate with comments in the OP which lines are uncovered); I'm going to hypothesize that you are not simulating in the testmethod the action of the getters and setters in the controller and these are the uncovered lines.  The testmethod should assign values to setters just as if the user did so and then ensure the getters are exercised either by the code or by a system.assert in the testmethod to see the values were properly set

Comment: Hello crop1645, thank you for your response i added in the code the lines that are  uncovered basically the the second section of the "CreatedPlan()" is uncovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the issue. Note that system.debug(..) is your friend here to discover why values aren't as expected

1. Your constructor initializes the list of `WrapServices` to size=1 for the test factory `Service__c`. The inner class is defaulted to `selected = false`
2. `ServiceProcessSelected()` - the next statement in the testmethod loops through the list of `WrapServices` but only creates members of list `selectedServices` if the inner class is selected - but none are.
3. Hence `selectedServices` is empty. Nothing else ever calls `ServiceProcessSelected()` again nor do you ever simulate the user actually selecting one of the inner class members that I can see.
4. Hence `createPlan` at line 87 `for (Service__c row: selectedServices)` has nothing to iterate and hence code is uncovered.

As an aside, I would remove the construction of `wrapServiceList` from the constructor and put it in the getter for property `wrapServiceList` - this is the principle of lazy loading and permits your controller to be used for other use cases wherein the SOQL for Service__c is only done when needed. Clean constructors are best.

Comment: thank you so much!!! you are right the line 87 was the problem.  SelectedServices was never populated.